# How to post tweets to multiple twitter accounts through "thujohn/twitter" library in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter

How to use the [`thujohn/twitter`](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter) library in Laravel framework to post tweets to multiple accounts that I manage on [twitter.com](http://twitter.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem when I've tried to publish on multiple twitter accounts before and I've solved it like this:

First: you need to create a [twitter app](https://apps.twitter.com) for each twitter account you manage, and from each app you need to get these data:

- API key (Consumer Key)
- API secret (Consumer Secret)
- Access token
- Access token secret

And here is how you are going to use them:

```
// set twitter app data of the twitter account you are going to publish to..
if (some_condition) 
{
    $consumer_key = "account_consumer_key";
    $consumer_secret = "account_consumer_secret";
    $access_token = "account_access_token";
    $access_token_secret = "account_access_token_secret";
} 
else if (some_other_condition) 
{
    $consumer_key = "account_consumer_key";
    $consumer_secret = "account_consumer_secret";
    $access_token = "account_access_token";
    $access_token_secret = "account_access_token_secret";
}

// set the new configurations
Twitter::reconfig([
    "consumer_key" => $consumer_key,
    "consumer_secret"  => $consumer_secret,
    "token" => $access_token,
    "secret" => $access_token_secret,
]);

$tweet = [
    'status' => "Some text that doesn't exceed 140 characters",
];

$tweet_result = Twitter::postTweet($tweet);
```

More info and credits goes to: [Hafsal](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/post-tweet-from-your-laravel-application-using-twitter-hafsal-m-e?forceNoSplash=true)